# Running a cucumber test on firefox in a docker container

Tags: ruby, selenium, docker, cucumber

I'm trying to run my cucumber tests in a docker container using firefox. I'm getting this error when my code just tries to visit 'google.com'

```
Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN gem update

ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --fix-missing iceweasel xvfb unzip

ENV   GECKODRIVER_VERSION v0.13.0
RUN   echo $GECKODRIVER_VERSION
RUN   mkdir -p /opt/geckodriver_folder
RUN   wget -O /tmp/geckodriver_linux64.tar.gz https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$GECKODRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz
RUN   tar xf /tmp/geckodriver_linux64.tar.gz -C /opt/geckodriver_folder
RUN   rm /tmp/geckodriver_linux64.tar.gz
RUN   chmod +x /opt/geckodriver_folder/geckodriver
RUN   ln -fs /opt/geckodriver_folder/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

ADD features /app/features
```

I've tried increasing my read_timeout to 120 with no effect.
When i bash into the container and run firefox it says "no display specified"

Any suggestions ?

Comment: try the `headless` gem. otherwise I'm not sure it's possible to run browser tests without a gui.

Comment: ...and `xvfb` is installed, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. This worked for me: https://github.com/juandelgado/docker-headless-firefox-cucumber/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4-slim
MAINTAINER Juan Delgado <juan@ustwo.com>

RUN mkdir /home/ustwo
WORKDIR /home/ustwo

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y xvfb build-essential libffi-dev wget firefox-esr && \
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.17.0/geckodriver-v0.17.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf geckodriver-v0.17.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
    chmod +x geckodriver && \
    mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin && \
    rm geckodriver-v0.17.0-linux64.tar.gz

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle

RUN ["cucumber", "--version"]
```